# Make One to One relation using entity framework code first approach?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, data-annotations

I just want to make a one to one relation between two table one table is USER and another table is USERDETAILS and USER table has a primary key USERID and USERDETAILS Table Has a key id[autogenerated] and also the USERID property for foreign key reference with user table ... but it gives some error when ever I try to create it.

models=>
user table

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "User Id Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(12, ErrorMessage = "You Have Exceed The Max length Of User ID which is [12] character!")]
    [RegularExpression("[1-3]{2}-[0-9]{5}-[123]{1}|[1-3]{2}-[0-9]{7}-[123]{1}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Id,It should [xx]-[xxxxx]-[x] or [xx]-[xxxxxxx]-[x]!")]
    [Display(Name = "User ID")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Password Max Length Is 20 Character!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string password { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "User Level Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length For User Level Is 100 Character!")]
    [RegularExpression("^(?:admin|Admin|student|Student)$" , ErrorMessage="Invalid User Level!")]
    [Display(Name = "User Level")]
    public string level { get; set; }

    //relationship with other table----

    public UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
}
```

and userdetails tablr=>

```
public class UserDetail
{
    [Key,Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// /////////////////////
    /// </summary>
    [Key,Column(Order = 1)]
    [MaxLength(12, ErrorMessage = "You Have Exceed The Max length Of User ID which is 12 Character!")]
    [RegularExpression("[1-3]{2}-[0-9]{5}-[123]{1}|[1-3]{2}-[0-9]{7}-[123]{1}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Id,It should [xx]-[xxxxx]-[x] or [xx]-[xxxxxxx]-[x]")]
    [Display(Name = "User ID")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ///////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Full Name Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length Of Full Name Is 100 Character!")]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string fullname { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ////////////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "First Name IS Required!")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length Of First Name Is 50 Character!")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// /////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Last Name Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length Of Last Name is 50 Character!")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ////////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Pic Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(700, ErrorMessage = "Your Destined Pic Path Is Too Much Long.The Max Length Of Picture Path Is 700 Character!")]
    [Display(Name = "Profile Pic")]
    public string pic_path { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ///////
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string company_name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// //////////
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string city { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Phone Number Is Required!")]
    [RegularExpression("[0-9]{7,11}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number!")]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public int phone_number { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// /////////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email Is Required!")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address!")]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string email { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// //////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Zip Code Is Required!")]
    [RegularExpression("[0-9]{4}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Zip Code!")]
    [Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
    public int zip_code { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// /////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Nationality Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length Of Nationality Is 30 Character!")]
    [Display(Name = "User Nationality")]
    public string nationality { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ////////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Gender Is Required!")]
    [RegularExpression("^(?:m|M|male|Male|f|F|female|Female)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Gender!")]
    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    public string sex { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ///////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Religion Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length Of Religion is 20 Character!")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Religion!")]
    [Display(Name = "Religion")]
    public string religion { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ////////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Blood Group Is Required!")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length Of Blood Group Is 50 character!")]
    [Display(Name = "Blood Group")]
    public string blood_group { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ///////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Date Of Birth Is Required!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date Of Birth")]
    [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    public DateTime dob { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ///////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "User Activation Is Required!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date!")]
    [Display(Name = "User Activation Date")]
    public DateTime user_activation_date { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// //////////
    /// </summary>
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date!")]
    [Display(Name = "User Deactivation Date")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> user_deactivation_date { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ///////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "User Current Status Is Required!")]
    [RegularExpression("^(?:active|Active|inactive|Inactive)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Status!")]
    [Display(Name = "User Current Status")]
    public string user_active { get; set; }

    //relationshipwith other tables-----

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

and the error=>

[image: Error]
and i try =>to change user table

```
public List<UserDetail> UserDetail { get; set; }
```

and that works for me but it creates==>
[image]

one to many relationship...but I want one to one. help me please..or any suggestion.....

Answer (score 0):

When you have a one-to-one, the database needs to know which end is the principal and which is the dependent. The reason is that one or the other must be added first, and that cannot happen if they are both dependent on each other. More likely than not, you'll want your `User` class to be the principal, while your `UserDetails` class will be the dependent. There's no way that I know to define this without using fluent configuration, though.

```
public class User
{
    ...

    public class Config : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        HasRequired(m => m.UserDetails).WithRequiredPrincipal(m => m.User)
    }
}
```

Then in your context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new User.Config()); 
}
```